# JMS error : Error while deserialising an object

Tags: java, jms, jms-topic, jms-serializer, weblog

Getting Following strange exception

```
weblogic.jms.commom.JMSException:[JMSClientExceptions:055115]Error deserialising an object 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.TestClass
```

To my surprise , this is not happening for all invocation/Transactions. Sometimes deserialisation happens with no issue and sometimes i'm facing this issue.
If its related to class path, then I should be getting this error on constant basis but the case here is quit strange. Any help highly appreciated.